# How to pass multiple parameters into Ui-grid filter in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have created a custom filter in AngularJs [UI-grid](http://ui-grid.info/).The filter is working fine with a single argument but when it comes to multiple values filter didn't work well.Please if any one knows how to pass multiple parameters into UI grid filter let me know.

**AngularJs Filter Method**

Filter will execute when button on click and redraw the grid according to user name.

```
    $scope.filterData = function(userName) {
           $scope.searchText = userName;
           $scope.tableData.data = $filter('filter')
            ($scope.TestData,
            $scope.searchText, undefined);
//how can i pass multiple param into filter like filtering based on user name and age

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass any number of parameters. But while using filter tag, use function instead of a single parameter.

See the code below for reference.

```
$scope.filterData = function(userName, secndParm, thirdParm,...) {          
           $scope.tableData.data = $filter('filter')
            ($scope.TestData, function (value, key) {
               return  (value.userName == userName || value.someText == secndParm || value.someAntherText == thirdParm);
            });
}
```

Comment: `value.userName` means cel value in the grid?

Comment: values are individual objects of the Array you are going to search the results for. So with this approach u can compare with each attribute(of each object) u wanna do.